# Using the value of a select option for the sql where clause of another select

Tags: php, html, mysql

Within the same same, how can i send the value from the first option box, and then use that value in the where clause of the second option box query?

I.e. i select a client, then the second selection box will only show me options that are relevant to that client.

Ideally it would be a single page that works fluidly

```
Client Selection:
<?php               //OPEN DROP DOWN BOX
include("../login/dbinfo.inc.php");
$comm=@mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
$rs=@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database"); 
$sql=   "SELECT DISTINCT ClientCode, ClientName FROM tbl_client ORDER BY ClientCode";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='ClientCode'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['ClientCode'] ."'>" . $row['ClientName'] ."</option>;
}
echo "</select><br>";   //CLOSE DROP DOWN BOX   

?><br>

Vessel Selection:
<?php               //OPEN DROP DOWN BOX
$client = $_GET["$client"];//assign client code from first drop down to this value & use in query 'WHERE' clause

include("../login/dbinfo.inc.php");
$comm=@mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
$rs=@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database"); 
$sql=   "SELECT VesselName  FROM tbl_import WHERE ClientCode='".$client."' ORDER BY VesselName";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='VesselName'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['VesselName'] ."'>" . $row['VesselName'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select><br>";   //CLOSE DROP DOWN BOX                                   
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

PHP is a server side language - all of the queries execute before it's received by the browser. If you want the content of your menu to change based on your first selection (the client), you'll either need to submit the form after you've selected the client OR use javascript to populate the second menu after the first menu has received a selection.

Second note - you're using `mysql` functions - those have been deprecated in PHP5 and removed in PHP7; look into at least updating your code to use `mysqli` functions.

Third note - you're inserting user data directly into your queries, meaning your opening your site to SQL injections. You can avoid that by using prepared statements and bound parameters through `mysqli` or (better still) `pdo` functions to access your database.

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for that, noted on the above. I havent tried it yet, but is it possible to do a form per field, that automatically executes on selection, with location #, and then get value from prev? just incase you do know, otherwise ill have to give it a try someh

Comment: Yes, you can set each field in its own form. And you can use Javascript to automatically submit the first form when a value is selected (`onChange="this.form.submit()"` added to the `<select>` tag.) to populate the second form. Its definitely less graceful, but will let you continue forward with what you're doing for now

Comment: Thank you so much lucas, the onChange is a great method for what i am trying to achieve, i understand its less graceful, but like you said, it does indeed allow me to continue with what i am working on. Thanks again!

Comment: one last thing lucas, with the above code that you showed me, is there a variation to make the form hidden on submit?

Comment: Its not a variant, it's more sloppiness. Since your form will be accessed initially by a GET request, but submitting the form will be done via POST, you could choose to show the first menu only if it was accessed through a GET REQUEST.

Therefore:

 `<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') { ?> 

Form 1

<?php } ?>

Or you could use a hidden field in your first form to accomplish this as well. We're really veering from your original question though :)